# Link to install Android app on the website - after installation, how can the app continue where the website left off?

Tags: android

Basically, there's a website with content that can also be viewed by a native app, and there's even a button on the site to do just that - which sends the user to the Play Store if the app's not on the device yet.

The idea is to make a 'seamless' transition into the app even if it hasn't been installed yet, so it can load the same content the moment it starts for the first time. If there was only one browser, something like this could've been done using cookies, but on an Android device you can have lots of browsers, and a lot of people apparently do. Authentication is not required to view the content, so it can't be that, either.

Is there a way to do such a seamless transition without hoping for the user to select the browser he was using to read the site?

Comment: Not quite what you want, but intent filters should let you send someone from the website to the right place in your app.

Comment: Yeah, that much is a given - but that's for the case when the app is already installed, I'm looking for a way to do the same thing when the app's not available yet. Kind of like establishing some unique id by the site that the app can somehow access after it's installed.

Comment: I think the best you could do is collect a whole bunch of information that is visible from both the browser and an app, and see if there's exactly one match within a few minutes of the first launch of the app (or sooner, if you use a hook like plan b does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a solution that would almost always work, though it is awkward:

1. Browser drops something into a cookie and the server keeps session data that keeps track of where the user is
2. When the app launches it launches it creates a UUID.
3. The app then launches the browser to a special page with the UUID as a GET parameter.
4. The UUID has now been matched up to the earlier session data on the server.
5. There's javascript on the page that sends the user back to the app by changing the URL to match an Intent filter.
6. The app can now request the session data from your server.

This is far from ideal, and would really slow down the first load of your app.

Comment: It seems that this is, in fact, how they do it on iOS (what with every browser using the same UIWebView), but there may be multiple browsers installed on an Android device and the user would most likely have to manually pick a browser when an app tries to launch a URL - this is what I'm trying to avoid. Although I guess if everything else fails I'll just have to put up a big red notice "please select the browser you were using".

Comment: On Android, you can't use a WebView, as all of the cookies will be different. I doubt most users regularly switch between different browsers, but if that becomes a problem, you could try a statistical approach, maybe combining time, IP address, version of Android, and model of phone to guess which browser to launch.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after a long while, we figured out that we could make do with passing the required parameters to the Play Store using the referral links generally reserved for campaign measurement and stats like that - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns - using a custom BroadcastReceiver to redirect the intent into the activity when it starts for the first time (the referrer intent only happens after the app has been launched and the activity has been started, so there's one more thing to be careful about).

Though it only works if you open the app link in the Play Store app, not in the browser. Hopefully most people do just that anyway.